# Ajuda com Compilação para Apk

Tags: unity3d

Opa, de boa?

Fui iniciar um projeto mobile pra sair um pouco da rotina de produzir .exe, e me deparei com um problema durante o processo de compilação de qualquer projeto, inicialmente achei que fosse um problema do jdk e do sdk, entretanto após testar com diversas versões do mesmo continuou sem funcionar.[image: OL]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mude o projeto de diretorio. Você esta utilizando caracteres especiais no diretorio.

C:\User\Usuário <<<<<<< Aki ta com caracter especial. Tenta mudar, deve funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o teu disco rigido não está cheio. Mantenha o sdk e o jdk que vem junto com a unity. Caso não resolver mande mais prints mostrando o os Player settings, e a aba Build